# How do I tail a block device in Linux?

Tags: linux, tail

I am trying to get just the last 1024 bytes of /dev/sda2. When I do `sudo tail -c 1024 /dev/sda2 | hd`, the prompt just hangs until I hit Ctrl-C. However, when I `tail -c 1024 ddfilecopyofsda2 | hd`, I immediately get a nice output of the last 1024 bytes of the file. I read here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60034/what-are-character-special-and-block-special-files-in-a-unix-system) that "Block devices are normally seekable," so what am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one way to get the last 1024 bytes of a block device:

```
last_bytes() { sudo dd if=$2 iflag=skip_bytes skip=$(($(sudo blockdev --getsize64 $2) - $1)) bs=1M ; } ; last_bytes 1024 DEVICE
```

Replace `DEVICE` with the device path.  In your case, you'd use `/dev/sda2`.

---

Now for a more interesting question to answer…

### Why does `tail -c 1024 /dev/sda2` search the entire disk?

The reason is how `tail` is implemented.  When `tail` knows the size of the file it's reading, it knows exactly how much to seek.  Otherwise, it has to read the file or stream all the way to find out how far to count back.

With pipes, it makes sense, like `cat /dev/sda2 | tail -c 1024`.  `tail` is receiving the contents as a stream and has no way of knowing when the data will end.

You might expect `tail -c 1024 /dev/sda2` to be able to figure out the size of `/dev/sda2`, but actually, when `tail` looks up `/dev/sda2`, it's opened as a block device instead of a regular file.

The implementation detail is that `tail` calls [`fstat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) to get information about the file.

#### `tail` on a regular file

Here's the relevant part of an `strace` of an example of `tail` opening a file:

```
21:30:27 open("/var/log/syslog", O_RDONLY) = 3
21:30:27 fstat(3, {st_dev=makedev(0, 22), st_ino=4715, st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_nlink=1, st_uid=104, st_gid=4, st_blksize=131072, st_blocks=54, st_size=175500, st_atime=2017/11/10-21:28:39.243133398, st_mtime=2017/11/10-21:30:20.438031639, st_ctime=2017/11/10-21:30:20.438031639}) = 0
21:30:27 lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)          = 0
21:30:27 lseek(3, 174476, SEEK_SET)     = 174476
```

`fstat()` provides `st_size=175500`.  Now `tail` just needs to count back 1024 bytes:

> 175500 - 1024 = 174476
>
> … and this is exactly what `tail` does:
>
> ```
> lseek(3, 174476, SEEK_SET)     = 174476
> ```

#### `tail` on a block device

`fstat()` doesn't return the size this time!:

```
21:29:43 open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY)     = 3
21:29:43 fstat(3, {st_dev=makedev(0, 6), st_ino=17488, st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=6, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_rdev=makedev(8, 0), st_atime=2017/11/10-09:21:15.643998960, st_mtime=2017/11/10-09:21:15.555998962, st_ctime=2017/11/10-09:21:15.555998962}) = 0
```

With no `st_size`, `tail` cannot know how far to seek, so it defaults to reading through the whole block device until the end.

This is why you should generally use block device tools like `dd` to manipulate block devices rather than tools intended for regular files like `tail`.

---

You might ask, "How does `blockdev --getsize64` quickly get the size of the block device?"

Here's `sudo strace -vvvfts1000 blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda`:

```
21:53:15 open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY)     = 3
21:53:15 ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE64, [512110190592]) = 0
```

`blockdev` is meant to get block device ioctls, and `BLKGETSIZE64` gets the size of the block device.

---

As for *why* `tail` doesn't do `BLKGETSIZE64`, I don't know.  The [source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) shows:

```
#define IS_TAILABLE_FILE_TYPE(Mode) \
  (S_ISREG (Mode) || S_ISFIFO (Mode) || S_ISSOCK (Mode) || S_ISCHR (Mode))
```

I only know from that line that without [`S_ISBLK()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Testing-File-Type.html), the authors didn't mean for `tail` to support block devices.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer about 5 times! Thank you for such a detailed explanation!

Comment: Note GNU dd since 8.16 (2012-03-26) supports the `iflag=skip_bytes` option. This allows one to efficiently skip an arbitrary portion of the input while being independent of the block size used for I/O. One often wants to use a large `bs` for efficiency.

Comment: Thanks @pixelbeat!  I've updated my answer to use `dd iflag=skip_bytes` instead.